# Scroll bar disappeared due to CSS conflict between custom html page and WordPress theme

Tags: css

Our website works on a 15 inch laptop, but we cannot scroll down as the scroll side bar disappeared.
When We remove the link between our website and main CSS.

The page that has the issue: https://singleclic.com/odoo/pricing-2/

We are using WordPress and the above page is a custom html page we have created.

When use the html code on a separate server without WordPress the issue disappear.

We did fix the issue by fixing the overflow by making it visible.

```
html, body, #wrapwrap{width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: visible;}
```

The issue now is the sidebar is not sticky as it should be
CSS Code

```
.position-sticky{position: sticky !important;}
```

Now the issue was fixed when we removed

```
  <div id="wrapwrap" class="    o_odoo_pricing ">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file web.assets_frontend.css gives the style `overflow: hidden` to your body element, remove this or add `overflow: auto` to your body element to solve this issue

[image]

Comment: It did fix the issue, however there is another issue appeared the side bar is not now a sticky one however it should be sticky on scroll

Comment: We have updated the question, please check it